# How to use Google Region Lookup API

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps

I have a problem integrating the Region Area Lookup from Google Maps. It's an experimental feature but I can't make it work.

I made a react application to try integrating this, but this is TypeScript and does not work. So I tried to convert my code into JavaScript, but it does not work at all.

Here is the page of the documentation : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/region-lookup

Maybe someone can explain me how can I make it work please?

I tried to make Google Region Lookup API works but without success.

Answer (score -1):

To integrate the Region Area Lookup API into your React or JavaScript application, follow these steps:

Prerequisites:
Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Account: Ensure you have a GCP account and have enabled the necessary APIs in the Google Cloud Console (specifically, the Maps JavaScript API and the experimental feature if it's available).
API Key: Obtain an API key from the GCP Console and enable billing to use the Maps JavaScript API.
Implementation:
Include the Google Maps JavaScript API script in your HTML file:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Initialize the map and define the Region Lookup:

```
// Make sure to replace YOUR_API_KEY with your actual API key
const YOUR_API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }, // Set the map center
    zoom: 8, // Set the initial zoom level
  });

  // Define the region lookup request
  const regionLookup = new google.maps.RegionLookup({
    key: YOUR_API_KEY, // Set your API key
    region: 'US', // Define the region (e.g., 'US' for United States)
    callback: (data) => {
      console.log(data); // Process the region data received
    },
  });

  // Perform the region lookup
  regionLookup.lookup(map.getCenter());
}
```

HTML container for the map:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Call the initMap() function:

```
<script async defer src="YOUR_JS_FILE.js" onload="initMap()"></script>
```

Ensure the API key you're using has the necessary permissions and is enabled for the experimental feature if it's still available.
Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual API key in the code.
Make sure your HTML container () matches where you want to display the map on your webpage.